# How to change mesibocall background and incall sound

Tags: android, kotlin, mesibo

I want to change mesibo call background and PlayInCallSound, this is the code I use to change background on incoming call using IncomingListener
[image]

How to custom background and incallsound using InProgressListener?, I already read the documentation but still have no idea, can someone provide sample code to do that?

Update:
I use mesibo answer below to set defaut ui properties after initialization and its work
[image]

Now i need to change in call sound using InProgressListener, but still didn't work, here's the code
[image]

Comment: Let's focus on resolving pending questions first. I see you have two other open questions - let's close those first, and then we can help you with this.

Comment: okay, i already close that

Comment: You can follow the mesibo docs to set background color: https://docs.mesibo.com/api/calls/callproperties/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InProgressListener` is invoked after the UI has already been initialized, which is too late to set UI properties like background color.

To set the UI background color and other UI properties, call the code below during app initialization:

```
MesiboCall.UiProperties ui = MesiboCall.getInstance().createCallProperties(true).ui;
ui.backgroundColor = 0xFF635478; // some random color
MesiboCall.getInstance().setDefaultUiProperties(ui);
```

Note that, mesibo uses hexadecimal ARGB color codes.

You can see an example of this in the mesibo sample app:

https://github.com/mesibo/samples/blob/master/android/kotlin/FirstAppKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/mesibo/firstapp/MainActivity.kt#L107

Comment: thanks it's solve the backgroud issues, now i need to custom sound when calling in progress, please see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The `CallUtils` used in your code is not part of the documented mesibo API, so I don't have details on what it does. If you are using, built-in but undocumented `CallUtils`, your code should work but we won't recommend it. What issue are you facing with the current code?

mesibo provides a `playInCallSound` function to play in-call sounds, which is part of the `MesiboCall.Call` class. However, it has a different signature than `CallUtils` which you have used and requires a `MesiboCall.Call` instance. Please refer to the code below from GitHub:

```
@Override
public boolean MesiboCall_OnPlayInCallSound(MesiboCall.CallProperties p, int type, boolean play) {
        if(!play) {
            mCall.stopInCallSound();
            return true;
        }

        mCall.playInCallSound(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), (MESIBOCALL_SOUND_RINGING == type)?R.raw.mesibo_ring :R.raw.mesibo_busy, true);
        return true;
}
```

https://github.com/mesibo/ui-modules-android/blob/master/MesiboCall/app/src/main/java/com/mesibo/calls/app/CallFragment.java#L394

Based on your previous question about the background color, it seems you may be customizing the UI and may not have created a `MesiboCall.Call` instance. Can you confirm if this is the case?

If you don't use a `MesiboCall.Call` instance, the easiest solution would be to configure call properties. Although `CallProperties` does not currently define in-call sound configuration, we could easily add that. Let me know if you prefer that and I can file an internal ticket.

Comment: Yes I'm using CallUtils from internal mesibo code because i didn't use MesiboCall.Call instance, please add inCallSound configuration via CallProperties

Comment: We have released v2.4 which also addresses incall sound configuration in the CallProperties. Please refer to the release note here https://docs.mesibo.com/changelog/v24/

Comment: Nice job, can you provide sample implementation in github?

Comment: We can certainly add an example soon. In the meantine, please set inCallRingSound, inCallBusySound in the CallProperties while making an outgoing call and let us know if any issues. They should be valid audio resources, the default one are here https://github.com/mesibo/ui-modules-android/tree/master/CallUi/calls/src/main/res/raw

Answer (score 0):

after update to mesibo v2.4 here's the code I use to change inCallSound

```
private fun makeCall(user: MesiboProfile, isVideo: Boolean) {
    val cp = MesiboCall.getInstance().createCallProperties(isVideo).apply {
        this.user = user
        inCallRingSound = R.raw.bp_calling_sound
    }
    CallManager.getInstance().callUi(cp)
}
```

Comment: This is correct. If you look at the GitHub link shared earlier, this is exactly how the internal code is, we only exported inCallRingSound in v2.4. If you are facing issue, please start with ring.mp3 which we used and then check if the sampling rate and the format is matching the ring.mp3